# Support ES6 module syntax along with CommonJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, commonjs, es6-modules

So I have this simple module:

```
export default function(){}
```

if I don't use `export default`, then the TypeScript compiler will write one warning saying my "module has no default export", which I'd like to avoid.

So to use this module, we would do:

```
import fn from 'my-module';
```

that's all good and well, but what if I want to use CommonJS to import it?

Then I have to do this:

```
const fn = require('my-module').default;
```

This is pretty awkward for users. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Perhaps I can add export = default. Which might be euivalent to module.exports = module.exports.default = fn...?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are equivalent:

```
import tscmultiwatch from 'tsc-multi-watch';
const {default:tscmultiwatch} = require('tsc-multi-watch');
```

That way you can avoid the less pleasant:

```
const tscmultiwatch = require('tsc-multi-watch').default;
```

And tsc-multi-watch might look like

```
export default function(){

}
```

Comment: “less pleasant”? Not really…